# Ideal of K[x,y], need for some precisions.

Tags: ideals

I was reading [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550729/x-1-a-1-x-2-a-2-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-kx-1-x-2) to show that $(x-a,y-b)$ is an ideal of $K[x,y]$, where $K$ is a field. The answer suggests to show that $(x-a,y-b)$ is the kernel of the evaluation in $ev_{(a,b)} : K[x,y] \rightarrow K$.
I understand that $ev_{(a,b)}(x-a)=0$ and $ev_{(a,b)}(y-b)=0$ so we have the inclusion $(x-a,y-b) \subset Ker(ev_{(a,b)})$ but how to show the other inclusion?

Comment: Hint: use polynomial division

Comment: This is evident $(x,y)$ is notation for ideal generated by $x,y$...

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov but is there a polynômial division in K[x,y]?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*
Write 
$ev_{(a,b)} = ev_{(0,0)} \circ \phi $, where $\phi$ is the automorphism of $K[x,y]$ given by $\phi(f(x,y))=f(x+a,y+b)$.

Then
$$
\ker ev_{(a,b)} = ev_{(a,b)}^{-1}(0) = \phi^{-1}(ev_{(0,0)}^{-1}(0)) = \phi^{-1}(\ker ev_{(0,0)})
$$

Comment: I am not sure I see how to make use of the hint.

Comment: @roi_saumon, see my edited answer